# How does one define the sum of N random variables in Python?

Tags: python, simulation, exponential-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Given $X_1 \cdots X_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim} exp(1)$ I want to show that $Y = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \stackrel{}{\sim} \chi^2_{2n}$

I proved it by computing the MGF of Y as

$M_{Y_1}(t) = M_{2\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_j}(t) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}M_{X_j}(2t) = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^n}$

which uniquely characterizes the chi-square distribution with n degrees of freedom

I want to write a simulation in Python that can verify the above result for some fixed n. How can I define n random variables and it's us in Python?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and remove LaTeX formatting on text? It is difficult to read.

Comment: @mhdadk done, sorry!

Comment: There are several random number libraries in Python that you can use to sample according to distributions you define. There's the standard library `random`, the `numpy.random`, and `scipy.stats`. Those are a good starting point for your exploration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [scipy-stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) package is useful if you are using Python. Here is a code-snippet to get you started - it generates one realisation of the random variable $Y$ using $n = 50$ iid copies of $X$. Have imported matplotlib as it is likely that you will need to plot histograms.

```
# Import modules.

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import expon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set number of iid copies of exp rv X ~ exp(1)
# Generate using scipy stats and compute transformation Y.

n = 50
X = expon.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=n)
Y = 2 * np.sum(X)
```

If you have a look at the documentation it will be clear how to tweak this for your purposes.